# Search doesn't link to specific blog in results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, blog

Situation:
I have a main SharePoint site and created blog as a subsite. I also created a search subsite and sending all the results there, from the main page and the blog.

Problem:
When I search for a term within a blog, it links me directly to the main blog, rather than the post itself.

How do I change it so it goes to the post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Query using "ContentType:Post" in the search results webpart of the search subsite. It will take you to the Post directly rather than linking to the main blog page.

Comment: that works perfectly but I don't want users to have to fill it out all the time - is it possible to add a search tab e.g. Everything, People, Conv, Videos and so on?